# Python: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'tmp/t_temp.txt']

Tags: python, macos

I have created a python executable with PyInstaller for macOS (I am working on macOS Big Sur 11.1) which does some stuff including creating files. I uploaded it to a repository. When I download and execute it within the download directory I get this exception:[Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'tmp/t_temp.txt'], but for example if I create a subdirectory in the download folder and move my application inside it works well as well as if I move it in any other folder.
Does anyone knows why and how I can solve such a problem?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to install something in a folder that's protected by SIP.

Comment: The file my application tries to save are .txt. Yes maybe you are right, but when I move the application somewhere and move it back in the download directory it works normally, is it possible that the the execution of the application (without moving it) makes the directory temporary read-only?

Comment: The file type is irrelevant, what matters is the directory that it's trying to install it into.

Comment: The error message doesn't say the directory is read-only, it says the **filesystem** is read-only. That's not something an installer would normally do.

Comment: is the download directory from a disk-image file? These are often mounted read-only.